# Voted to Close for the Wrong Reason

Tags: support

So... I voted on a question to close it, but then I accidentally clicked on the wrong reason. So I retracted the close vote in an attempt to choose the correct reason, however the question no longer allows me to vote to close, as it says I have already voted.

Is this the correct behavior for this?

And if so, is there a way to change the vote to close reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the standard behaviour and that I feel it's kind of wrong. If this question where posted in [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.se) instead of meta.sp.se you would get loads of upvotes and comments on why this is bad behaviour of a system.

I'd suggest a timer just as the one we have on votes, where you can regret a vote in 15 minutes, to currect yourself. The same would be a nice feature on closing votes.